Error with ContainerConfig in GitHub Actions
I'm currently trying to deploy on Google Cloud Engine (GCE) using a Makefile and docker-compose.yml. 
When I execute the command make community-update on the GCE server, everything works fine. However, when I use the same command in GitHub Actions, I encounter the following error:
Github Actions Error Log:
...
out: sleep 10...
out: sleep 30
out: community-service update start
out: docker-compose up -d community-service
err: redis-community is up-to-date
err: zookeeper is up-to-date
err: mariadb-community is up-to-date
err: kafka is up-to-date
err: discovery-service is up-to-date
err: gateway-service is up-to-date
err: Recreating community-service ... 
err: [64003] Failed to execute script docker-compose
err: ERROR: for community-service  'ContainerConfig'
err: ERROR: for community-service  'ContainerConfig'
err: Traceback (most recent call last):
err:   File "docker-compose", line 3, in <module>
err:   File "compose/cli/main.py", line 81, in main
err:   File "compose/cli/main.py", line 203, in perform_command
err:   File "compose/metrics/decorator.py", line 18, in wrapper
err:   File "compose/cli/main.py", line 1186, in up
err:   File "compose/cli/main.py", line 1182, in up
err:   File "compose/project.py", line 702, in up
err:   File "compose/parallel.py", line 108, in parallel_execute
err:   File "compose/parallel.py", line 206, in producer
err:   File "compose/project.py", line 688, in do
err:   File "compose/service.py", line 581, in execute_convergence_plan
err:   File "compose/service.py", line 503, in _execute_convergence_recreate
err:   File "compose/parallel.py", line 108, in parallel_execute
err:   File "compose/parallel.py", line 206, in producer
err:   File "compose/service.py", line 496, in recreate
err:   File "compose/service.py", line 615, in recreate_container
err:   File "compose/service.py", line 334, in create_container
err:   File "compose/service.py", line 922, in _get_container_create_options
err:   File "compose/service.py", line 962, in _build_container_volume_options
err:   File "compose/service.py", line 1549, in merge_volume_bindings
err:   File "compose/service.py", line 1579, in get_container_data_volumes
err: KeyError: 'ContainerConfig'
err: make: *** [Makefile:40: community-update] Error 255

I am attaching my Makefile, docker-compose.yml, and GitHub Actions workflow yml for reference.
Makefile:
community-update:
        @echo "community temp start"
        docker-compose up -d community-service-temp
        sleep 50
        docker-compose pull community-service
        @echo "sleep 10..."
        sleep 30
        @echo "community-service update start"
        docker-compose up -d community-service
        @echo "sleep 60..."
        sleep 60

        @echo "community temp remove"
        @echo "1. find container id"
        @container_id=$$(docker ps | grep community-service-temp | grep -v 'CONTAINER' | awk '{print $$1}'); \
        echo $$container_id; \
        echo "2. remove community temp"; \
        docker exec -i $$container_id kill -15 $$(docker exec -i $$container_id lsof -i | grep java | awk 'NR==1 {print $$2}'); \
        docker rm -f $$container_id; \
        docker image prune -f

docker-compose.yml:
community-service:
    image: {username}/community-service:1.0
    container_name: community-service
    environment:
      jasypt.encryptor.password: ${JASYPT_PASSWORD}
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - kafka
      - redis-community
      - mariadb-community
      - discovery-service
      - gateway-service
community-service-temp:
    image: {username}/community-service:1.0
    container_name: community-service-temp
    environment:
      jasypt.encryptor.password: ${JASYPT_PASSWORD}
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - kafka
      - redis-community
      - mariadb-community
      - discovery-service
      - gateway-service
      - community-service

Github Actions Workflow:
name: CommunityService CI/CD

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - 'BE/dev'
    paths:
      - 'src/backend/community-service/**'

jobs:
  build-and-push:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          submodules: false
          token: ${{ secrets.COMMUNITY_ACTION_TOKEN }}

      - name: Configure Git to use PAT for submodules
        run: |
          git config --global url."https://${{ secrets.COMMUNITY_ACTION_TOKEN }}@github.com/".insteadOf "https://github.com/"

      - name: Initialize specific submodules
        run: |
          git submodule init src/backend/community-service/community-service-yml
          git submodule update --remote src/backend/community-service/community-service-yml

      - name: Update nested submodules within specific submodule
        run: |
          cd src/backend/community-service/community-service-yml
          git submodule update --init --recursive

      - name: Cache Gradle dependencies
        uses: actions/cache@v2
        with:
          path: |
            ~/.gradle/caches
            ~/.gradle/wrapper
          key: gradle-${{ hashFiles('**/*.gradle*', '**/gradle-wrapper.properties') }}
          restore-keys: |
            gradle-

      - name: Set up JDK 17
        uses: actions/setup-java@v2
        with:
          java-version: '17'
          distribution: 'temurin'

      - name: Grant execute permission for gradlew
        run: chmod +x src/backend/community-service/gradlew

      - name: Project Build
        env:
          jasypt.encryptor.password: ${{ secrets.JASYPT_PASSWORD }}
        working-directory: ./src/backend/community-service
        run: ./gradlew clean build
        shell: bash

      - name: Login to DockerHub
        uses: docker/login-action@v1
        with:
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD }}

      - name: Docker Image Build
        run: docker build -t ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}/community-service:1.0 ./src/backend/community-service

      - name: Docker Image Push
        run: docker push ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}/community-service:1.0

      - name: GCP 인스턴스 접속 및 무중단 배포
        uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
        with:
          host: ${{ secrets.GCP_HOST }}
          username: ${{ secrets.GCP_USERNAME }}
          key: ${{ secrets.GCP_SSH_KEY }}
          script: |
            cd script
            make community-update

This error doesn't occur when running directly on a GCE server. Can anyone help me understand why it happens on GitHub Actions?

I've experimented with logging into Docker from the script and then executing commands.
I've also tried running the make community-update command using sudo.

